# React-Native: Return to app after Facebook login?

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am building an app with react-native. I have implemented facebook login using this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login.

When pressing the "Log in with Facebook" button in the app, it takes me to the facebook web page and asks me to give the app permission to use some of my personal information. I accept, but it never takes me back to the app.

Any suggestions on how to make it so I get redirected back to the app?

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native'

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk')
const {
  LoginButton
} = FBSDK

class Login extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert("Login failed with error: " + result.error)
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert("Login was cancelled")
              } else {
                alert("Login was successful with permissions: " + result.grantedPermissions)
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to the Facebook SDK for React Native!</Text>
        <Login />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you connected the AppDelegate class to the FBSDKApplicationDelegate object? If not, this is probably the issue.

Check out the **Connect App Delegate** section [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started).

It basically says to add this code to AppDelegate.m :

```
//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

I've implemented this into my AppDelegate class in another project, [here](https://gist.github.com/dabit3/24ace6a1f6973ed8675fb37a211f3c4c) is what mine looks like after the new code was added:

https://gist.github.com/dabit3/24ace6a1f6973ed8675fb37a211f3c4c

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTRootView.h"

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

//  for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
//  {
//    NSLog(@"%@", family);
//    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
//    {
//      NSLog(@" %@", name);
//    }
//  }

  /**
   * Loading JavaScript code - uncomment the one you want.
   *
   * OPTION 1
   * Load from development server. Start the server from the repository root:
   *
   * $ npm start
   *
   * To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer
   * (you can get this by typing `ifconfig` into the terminal and selecting the
   * `inet` value under `en0:`) and make sure your computer and iOS device are
   * on the same Wi-Fi network.
   */

  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

  /**
   * OPTION 2
   * Load from pre-bundled file on disk. The static bundle is automatically
   * generated by the "Bundle React Native code and images" build step when
   * running the project on an actual device or running the project on the
   * simulator in the "Release" build configuration.
   */

//  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"YOURAPPNAME"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation];
}

@end
```

Comment: I also missed the `openURL` part of the tutorial, adding that section to my AppDelegate worked for me too.